# Xcode Error using Pthread: Thread 2 Signal SIGABRT

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, terminal, pthreads

I tried doing some Googling on this issue, but it seems most people have SIGABRT errors when working on iOS apps in Xcode.  My issue is related to a concurrent C++ terminal application.  I am getting the error `Thread 2 Signal SIGABRT` on random runs of my software and it is always on a `pthread_mutex_lock()` or `pthread_mutex_unlock()` calls.  Are there any known issues with Pthread in this regard or does this error directly come down to user error?  I would like to post some code, but I currently don't have the right to.  I was hoping someone who is familiar with Pthread can tell me if this is an issue with the library or not.

Also, when I run the binary outside of Xcode through terminal, I sometimes get an `abort trap: 6` error when using similar inputs that I use to trigger the SIGABRT error in Xcode.  Are these definitely two separate errors, or could they be linked?

Comment: There's one or more bugs in your code. The errors may be separate or they may be linked. It's impossible to guess what exactly these bugs could be.

Comment: My code is rather long (a few hundred SLOC) and I'm not sure what is causing these errors, so I don't even know what to remove to make a shorter workable version with the same errors.  Although, the SIGABRT error always shows up o the same two lines, when it does show up.  Would a link to a repo work?